# How to know the mac emulator used font family using React Native

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am new to mobile app using react native .In web application what font family is applied i can know with using firebug or other.But using react native in emulator what font family is applied i am unable to find it.By default system font family is applied but in mac i don't that also.Please give the clarification regarding this font family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is iOS the one setting the default font and it changed over time:

- iOS6 -> iOS8: `Helvetica Neue Regular`
- iOS9: `San Francisco`

If you want to know the specific font of a `<Text>` in your app you can use the built-in inspector: `control + ⌘ + z` -> `Show Inspector`  (although it won't show if it was not explicitly set)